# How to find Directory in Linux using c?

Tags: c, linux

I'm making a c program in linux where a user could enter the directory name to be found. I
Following is the code I have written but not getting the correct output. I'm searching through all directories till I found the directory.
I'm just a beginner.

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<dirent.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<errno.h>

void findDir(char *dir, char *name)
{
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *entry;
    struct stat statbuf;

    if((dp = opendir(dir)) == NULL)
    {
        printf("\ncan not open directory: %s", name);
        printf("\nDescription: %s", strerror(errno));
        return;
    }

    chdir(dir);

    while(( entry = readdir(dp)) != NULL)
    {
        lstat( entry->d_name, &statbuf);
        if(S_ISDIR( statbuf.st_mode))
        {
            if( strcmp(name,entry->d_name) == 0)
            {
                printf("Dir found");
                return;
            }
            findDir(entry->d_name, name);
        }
    }
    chdir("..");
    closedir(dp);
}

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if( argc != 2 )
    {
        printf("Error");
    }
    else
    {
        findDir("/home", argv[1]);
    }
}
```

Please Help!!
I get the follwing output while giving **Documents** as argument. Actually program goes infinite and i repeteadly get the following output. This is just a little of the output.

> can not open directory: Documents
>   Description: Too many open files
>   can not open directory: Documents
>   Description: Too many open files
>   can not open directory: Documents
>   Description: Too many open
>   filesDir found

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the output you are getting?

Comment: Yes, please add output and for debugging add printf on name,entry->d_name just before strcmp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a quick look at this.  Here is some advice.

- When debugging, either single-step in a debugger or at least put some print statements to see what is really happening.  I put in a `printf()` in the loop that walks the directories, and found that right away it is trying to visit the `..` directory, so it leaves `/home` and loops forever.
- So, in your loop, before you do anything else, test to see if `entry->d_name` is `"."` or `".."`, and if so, skip that directory entry (you can just use the `continue` keyword).
- Make sure you call `closedir(dp);` before the function returns.  For example, when your code prints the message `can not open directory:`, your function returns without closing the directory.  By the way, you should print `entry->d_name` in that error message, not `name`.

The error `Too many open files` is because your loop is following `..` so it will never stop, and it finds plenty of directories it cannot open, so the code not calling `closedir()` on error exit means more and more directories are left open.

- Your program will keep on going after it finds the target directory!  It will print a message but keep on going.  You can modify your function `findDir()` to return a code saying whether it found the target or not, and make your program stop in this case.

Comment: I tried it, although it has stopped to loop forever but still not getting the requireed result. Following is the the output:  

    ./a.out Documents  
  
    can not open directory: Documents  
    Description: Too many open files

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that [`readdir()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir) is **not** re-entrant. It relies on an internal buffer which, when you recurse, is being overwritten. If you're using a POSIX standard, you can try [`readdir_r`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir_r) which is re-entrant.

Or, you can read the directory into a list before you start to recurse, then process the items in the list one at a time. That way you've read the entire directory before you try to dive down the next level in the directory tree and the entries at the current level won't be lost to the overwrite at the deeper level.

Answer (score 2):

Another problem you're going to run into here (and the one that's probably affecting you most right now) is that the special directory entries `.` and `..` will show up in the results from `opendir()`/`readdir()`. You will need to check for and skip these two using something along the lines of:

```
if (!strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(entry->d_name, ".."))
    continue;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll better use the [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) library function, which is able to walk recursively thru a file tree.

If you are not allowed to use it, you could at least study its source, e.g. from the [MUSL libc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) file [src/misc/nftw.c](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/misc/nftw.c) which I find quite readable.

BTW, your call to `lstat` is wrong in your code, you need to construct the entire file path.

You need to use the `gdb` debugger on your program. You may also want to use `strace` to understand which syscalls it is doing (and `strace`-ing some `find` command would also teach you many things).